# How can I get all Facebook Page Categories and Areas using c#

Tags: c#, facebook, api, categories

My application needs to show the user all Page categories available so he can choose which pages to follow and / or Like. Is there any way using the api in c# to get all the categories?

I also need to get all areas available in Facebook used as location and/or Home town etc.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research, it doesn't seem possible.  The Facebook FQL requires a where clause to search pages.  This means you need to provide one of the following: a keyword, a page_id, a name, or a username.  Since you don't seem to have any of these fields, or more specifically you want everything, so these fields are unimportant to you.  To sum up: `select categories from pages` is not valid FQL, it have a where clause.  Example:

```
select categories from pages where page_id = x
select categories from pages where keyword = x
select categories from pages where name = x
select categories from pages where username = x
```

This seems odd to me, since if one navigates to https://www.facebook.com/pages the site is certainly capable of enumerating the pages available.  If you had simply an enumeration of all pages on the site, you could build your own list of categories based on a massive recursive search.  This would need to be done infrequently and stored locally to your application.

To answer the second part of your question FQL allows to search for posts that have been tagged with location data (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/location_post) however this will only return results based on the following 4 rules:

- you were tagged in the Post
- a friend was tagged in the Post
- you authored the Post
- a friend authored the Post

The "you" they are referring to here is the owner of the OAuth token used to execute the query.  Again, I do not believe this would result in you being able to retrieve a list of locations due to the same `where` clause limitation as seen above.

This ends the section of official Facebook API.  You can certainly fall back on basic web page scraping, similar to the answer provided by Silamril.  However I'm not sure if this will work for locations since that search box seems to be a live search autocomplete box.  This means you have to put something in to get something out.  I suggest you look at a geoapi provider or even simply scrape a wikipage like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lists_of_settlements_in_the_United_States.  There are providers of mapping information out there like OpenStreetMap that will be able to provide you with the same information in an API format.  See the OSM wiki (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:place).

Answer (score 0):

You can acquire all page categories with a script like on https://gist.github.com/bloudermilk/2173940